# NavigationService Xamarin with Prism and Autofact can't find my navigation

Tags: xamarin, prism, autofac

I register my Xamarin form page with Autofac container on my App that inherits PrismApplication för Autofac

```
_container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MasterLayoutPage_View, MasterLayoutPageViewModel>("MasterLayoutPage");
```

Then I navigate like this:

```
  await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterLayoutPage");
```

But it always says that MasterLayoutPage is not registered. 
But when I check my Container for registered types it's there, fully added as the registration above.

Have I missed something? It worked with Unity I just change to Autofac.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I found this kind of odd and wonder if it might be a bug or if NavigationService with Autofact can't register the type as Unity can?

Comment: Can you provide a sample that reproduces the issue? This is the sort of problem where you really need to provide code in order for anyone to give you help beyond guessing. That said you're transitioning from Unity and aren't familiar with Autofac I would really suggest you look at using DryIoc instead.

Comment: I am fully familiar with Autofac used it many years now... But in this case its problem with the navigationservice. All types are registered as shown in the images... So even if the PageNavigationRegistery show me that my MasterpageLagout  is there (see last image) and the container (second image) it still throw the first image exception. 

I can't give you more code than just PrismApplication got the Container I use for registration.And then the line for navigation. There is nothing more to add... Using Nuger of Prism.Autofac

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my problem was that I did not register the pages inside the override method RegisterTypes on App.xaml.cs I registered the types on the Initialize overridden method. It did work with Unity, not sure why it does not work the same way with autofac when it's the same container I use... Maybe prismApplication for unity has some difference then PrismApplication for Autofac, I shall take a look at the implementations of those two

Comment: The only difference between the two is the your service are registered with the ContainerBuilder and the Container is then updated. Regardless of the Container you need to register the types before you try to navigate.

Comment: I had all types registered before navigation but I did the registration on Application OnInitialize and then navigated as in my main question. All types was registered though I found all types in the Container and Page Register before calling Navigation, but it got the null ref exception...
But if I registered the pages in RegisterTypes it worked even if the Register page and container show me the same result before navigaton. 

With Unity I had no problem to register the pages OnInitialize level.

Comment: If there is something you see working with Unity that isn't working with Autofac then please open an Issue on GitHub with sample code to show us what exactly the scenario is. Tks.